# how to communicate from a server to client using OPC UA protocol using python

Tags: python, server, client, opc-ua, communication-protocol

How do you communicate between a server and a client using the OPC UA protocol with python?
I'm very new to python and my colleague asked me to do this.
I didn't understand the question very well myself, but i was hoping you could help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [FreeOpcUa Python bindings](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua) yet?